# Bug in chrome with ckeditor editing links

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, ckeditor

So basically I have this problem in chrome(Working fine in Firefox). When I edit a content and I have the following  situation , a link and some text and when I click at the end of the link to change  "some link text" to "some link to website" it does the following

Before editing :

[some link text](http://nowhere) some content

```
<a href="">some link text </a> some content
```

[some link](http://nowhere) to website some content

```
<a href="">some link</a> to website some content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround as i did not need link popup and advance link popup i converted all  links to span and on save change them back to links

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue in CKEditor: https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11998

The only workaround would be to type text before the end of that link, and then delete unnecessary characters from the end.

In case of your example start typing "to website" before "text", and then delete "text".

Answer (score 1):

This is also the case in Safari (and Chrome) on MacOS.  The status bar shows 'body p a' when typing starts, but the 'a' part disappears after the first key stroke.  I wish I had a solution for you, but my guess is you'd have to report the issue to the CKEditor folks.